# How to unpack and reshape a list of arrays when passing it as function parameter in Python

Tags: python, arrays

When I run the following code

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(100, 2)
rv_values, bins_values = np.histogramdd(x, bins=100, density=True)
meshed_coordinates = np.meshgrid(*bins_values)
```

the `meshed_coordinates` variables becomes a list or two arrays of dimension `(101,101)`.
This is not a surprise since passing `bins=100` to `np.histogramdd` in the example returns the list `bins_values` which contains two 1D arrays of length `101`.

I want to use the operator `*` in  `np.meshgrid(*bins_values)` in such a way it passes the list `bins_values` with shortened arrays, for example  `bins_values[0][:-1]` and `bins_values[1][:-1]`, without the need of shorten them one by one outside the function call (or, for arbitrary lengths of the list, by resorting to a `for` loop that shorten each array in the list outside the function call).

Answer (score 1):

you may use the center of each bin?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(100, 2)
rv_values, bins_values = np.histogramdd(x, bins=100, density=True)
bins_values[0] = (bins_values[0][:-1] + bins_values[0][1:])/2
bins_values[1] = (bins_values[1][:-1] + bins_values[1][1:])/2
meshed_coordinates = np.meshgrid(*bins_values)
```

Comment: I don't want to explicitly use `bins_values[0], bins_values[1]` anywhere in the code. Imagine the case where the arrays in the list `bins_values` is not 2 any longer. I wish a general solution.

Comment: You may try with a list comprehension to generalise. You may also try to generalize by yourself

Comment: Ok, a list of comprehension may be neat, but I wonder if there is any syntax that allows you to shorten the arrays in the list directly in the function call. (I updated the question for the sake of adding more clarity).